# debugging Android application (in Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

Can anybody help me in finding good video-lessons for learning main debug skills and functions in Eclipse? 
If someone have good clear videos or interesting lessons for beginner write here please!

Comment: there isn't actually much to learn :) click on debug, the emulator for your android apps start, place breakpoints wherever you need them and have a look at the current state... Debugging for java isn't actually big magic for 99% of your use cases. Still wondering why a lot of people work with System.out.println :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqHYbm9e05A Though as Matthias said, there is no rocket science about it. Put breakpoints, click on debug and run your software =D